# Appointment Program In Ruby

Tags: beginner, ruby, homework

For a homework assignment for an online class (pretty much learning everything from the internet anyway) we were asked to build an appointment program. This is just a start, however I feel I am definitely over-complicating things and going about this the complete wrong way.

**These were the instructions we were given:**

> Implement a superclass `Appointment` and sub classes `OneTime`, `Day` and `Month`. An appointment has a description (for example, "Root Canal"), and dates information (you can use `Date` object or Int Year, Int Month, Int Day). Fill an array of Appointment objects with a mixture of appointments.
>
> Write a method `OccursOn` inside each of the sub classes that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date (`OneTime`), day (`Day`) or month (`Month`). Ask the user to enter a date to check (for example, `2006 10 5`), and ask to user if they want to check against `OneTime`, `Day` or `Month` appointment. Based on what the user selected, `OccursOn` inside each of the sub class should run and display any matching appointment and associated descriptions.

```
require 'date'

class Appointment
    attr_accessor :info, :date, :year, :day, :month
    def initialize(info, date)
        @info = info
        @date = Date.parse(date)
    end
    
    def get_info
        @info
    end
    
    def get_date
        @date
    end
    
    def get_year
        @year = date.year
    end
    
    def get_month
        @month = date.mon
    end

end

class OneTime < Appointment
    
    def OccursOn(year, month, day)
        puts "The year you entered is #{year}"
        puts "The month you entered is #{month}"
        puts "The day you entered is #{day}"
        appointments.each do |x|
            puts "Month #{x.get_month}"
            if x.get_month == month
                puts x.get_date
                puts x.get_info
            end
        end
    end
    
end

class Day < Appointment
    
    def OccursOn(day)
        puts day
    end
    
end

class Month < Appointment
    
    def OccursOn(month)
        puts month
    end
end

appointments = []
appointment1 = Appointment.new("Root Canal", "31/10/2017")
appointment2 = Appointment.new("Cavity Filling", "31/12/2017")
appointments << appointment1 << appointment2
puts appointment1.get_date
puts appointment2.get_date
puts appointment1.get_info

onetime1 = OneTime.new("Root Canal", "31-10-2017")

puts "Enter a date to check (for example, 31-10-2017)"
checkdate = gets.chomp
checkdate = Date.parse(checkdate)

puts "Would you like to check against OneTime, Day or Month appointment?"
checkagainst = gets.chomp

if checkagainst == "OneTime" or checkagainst == "onetime"
    onetime1.OccursOn(checkdate.year, checkdate.month, checkdate.day)
elsif checkagainst == "Day" or checkagainst == "day"
    puts "Day" # run day check function 
elsif checkagainst == "Month" or checkagainst == "Month"
    puts "Month" # run month check function
else
    puts "Invalid option."
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I feel I am definitely overcomplicating things

I agree with you that the code is longer than necessary. Let's take a look.

## YAGNI - you ain't gonna need it

Try to avoid writing code until a caller (such as a test method for a Story) *forces* you to write it. Then you know you really need it.

```
attr_accessor :info, :date, :year, :day, :month
```

The first two look good. I didn't notice any compelling reason to list y,m,d, as caller could get those from `date`. The `day` might be called `mday` for consistency with library.

```
def get_info
    @info
end

def get_date
    @date
end
```

Ummm, didn't `attr_accessor` already take care of those? We're writing in ruby, not java. Take advantage of its strengths!

I commented above that `get_year` & `get_month` seem redundant. Also, it seems odd to list them without `get_mday` (or perhaps `get_day`). Better to elide them entirely.

```
    appointments.each do |x|
```

This seems to be a global reference. I can't imagine that's a good thing. Consider moving that list into a class, such as the `Appointment` class.

```
        if x.get_month == month
```

I suggest it would be more natural to phrase that as `x.date.mon`.

Your recurring `Day` & `Month` classes appear to be unimplemented stubs, so far.
You have a design decision to make. Will adding a recurring appointment create several new entries until a date "very far" in the future? Or will it add a single entry and then you deal with that at query time? There is no right answer; each offers its own trade-offs.

```
puts "Would you like to check against OneTime, Day or Month appointment?"
checkagainst = gets.chomp
```

This seems a cumbersome UX. Rather than prompting, simply loop over all three, reporting the appointment and its type whenever you find a match.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! How would you recommend putting the appointments array into the class to avoid the global reference?

Comment: It seems likely that you want a container class, such as `PersonalCalendar`, which can add various sorts of appointments in a conflict-free way, and also respond to date queries. That would be a natural place to put it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not certain on how to complete that.